# Margin-top between firefox is difference from Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My styling in **CSS** is working well with *Chrome* but works differently from *Firefox*.

**HTML** Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="warning" data-on="公開 <div class='toggle_on'></div>" data-off="<div class='toggle_off'></div> 非公開">
```

Here is my **CSS** code :

```
.toggle_on {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 13px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -5px;
    -moz-margin-top:-25px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 20px -2px rgba(117,112,117,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 7px 20px -2px rgba(117,112,117,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 20px -2px rgba(117,112,117,1);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

and here are the result in *Chrome* :

[image]

and this one in *Firefox*:

[image]

so any idea with this??

Comment: Please post html too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This errors happen not because of CSS but because of HTML Code:

Code Before :

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="warning" data-on="公開 <div class='toggle_on'></div>" data-off="<div class='toggle_off'></div> 非公開">
```

and change to this :

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="warning" data-on="<div class='toggle_on'></div> 公開" data-off="<div class='toggle_off'></div> 非公開">
```

and it will work fine for all browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

first: Welcome to the world of web-development and differences between browsers.

> > so any idea with this??

maybe whitespace between the html-nodes. (although it shouldn't matter, in some cases it does)

Explanation: multiple whitespaces collapse to a single space, but this single character, this single space, still occupies some space in your layout ... sometimes.